# Attempting to compile opencv 3.2.0 with cuda 9.0

Tags: opencv, cmake, cuda

this is pretty self explanatory, my end goal is to compile opencv with cuda support for python. I'm on a windows 10 machine, anaconda 3.5, visual studio 2017. I've installed the various tools described in [This](https://jamesbowley.co.uk/build-opencv-v3-2-with-cuda-8-0-and-intel-mkltbb/) tutorial, but here is my error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/FindCUDA.cmake:1078 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    C:/Users/mikep/Desktop/OpenCV Files/Builds/Mike_OpenCV_Cuda_Windows(3.2.0-9.0.176)/opencv-3.2.0/cmake/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:50 (find_package)
  cmake/OpenCVDetectCUDA.cmake:16 (find_host_package)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:57 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:558 (include)


CMake Error at cmake/FindCUDA.cmake:1111 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    C:/Users/mikep/Desktop/OpenCV Files/Builds/Mike_OpenCV_Cuda_Windows(3.2.0-9.0.176)/opencv-3.2.0/cmake/FindCUDA/select_compute_arch.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:50 (find_package)
  cmake/OpenCVDetectCUDA.cmake:16 (find_host_package)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLibsPerf.cmake:57 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:558 (include)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: OpenCV is not yet fully compatible with cuda 9.0, you can refer to my answer [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46614298/888688) for details how to make it work (or at least compile).  In your error it seems that it is trying to include a cmake file that does not exist?  it is not in the github repository either, not sure if you modified the cmake files or download them for somewhere else... try downloading it again from the [repo](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/3.2.0) or if you prefer the latest [download here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master)

Comment: You can follow @api55's steps or you can get the source from the 3.3 master branch.

Comment: @MFisherKDX Until last week, the master branch didn't have the CUDA 9.0 fixes.... I installed that one actually

Comment: @api55.  Interesting.  I thought it worked a few weeks ago.  Oh well.  Here are my posts about the issue on the opencv forum.  http://answers.opencv.org/question/175221/unable-to-build-opencv-330-with-cuda-90-on-linux/    http://answers.opencv.org/question/175839/fail-to-build-opencv-330-with-opencv_contrib-330-and-cuda-toolkit-90

Comment: I kept having make and build issues, so I rolled back to VS 15 and CUDA 8.0, now im just hassling with python debug libs