# Report the location where find_package(Foo) found FindFoo.cmake

Tags: cmake

First, there is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46614298/1270789) that describes how to fiddle with `FindCUDA.cmake` so that we can link with CUDA 9.0+'s renamed NPP libraries correctly, but the default CMake 3.5.1 in Ubuntu 16.04 requires this code to be added manually.

However, if someone forgets to apply that change, or search paths are such that an older `FindCUDA.cmake` is picked up, I want to report an error. This code almost does that:

```
find_package(CUDA)
if (CUDA_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL "9.0")
    if (NOT CUDA_nppial_LIBRARY)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "CUDA 9.0+ libraries not set in file at ${FINDCUDA_FILE}")
    endif()
    target_link_libraries(foo ${CUDA_nppial_LIBRARY})
endif()
```

Except that I don't know what to use for `${FINDCUDA_FILE}` and searching the code doesn't give me any clues. Is there such a variable or other way to find that file?

Comment: You can probably use `CUDA_DIR` variable.

Comment: @arrowd: According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/command/find_package.html#search-procedure), `XXX_DIR` variable contains the directory with `XXXConfig.cmake`, but not with `FindXXX.cmake` script.

Comment: @arrowd `CUDA_DIR` is empty for me.

Comment: note: acording to the doc: > The full path to the configuration file is stored in the cmake variable <PackageName>_CONFIG
-> BUT there is no <PackageName>_MODULE
src: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Source/cmFindPackageCommand.cxx