# I've tried many things, but I can't install OpenCV 3.1 in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, opencv, ubuntu, cmake, opencv3.0

I tried to install opencv 3.1 to install Torch-opencv. However, the following error occurred while using the cmake. How can I fix this error?

My development environment uses Ubuntu 20.04 version through WSL2.

I've reinstalled all of my libraries and deleted and reinstalled them to prevent damage to my build files.

```
rm -rf build
❯ mkdir build
❯ cd build
❯ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
> -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
> -D WITH_TBB=ON \
> -D WITH_V4L=OFF \
> -D WITH_LIBV4L=ON \
> -D WITH_QT=ON \
> -D WITH_IPP=OFF \
> -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
> -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
> -D WITH_1394=OFF \
> -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
> -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
> -D CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-D_FORCE_INLINES" \
> -D BUILD_WITH_DEBUG_INFO=OFF \
> -D BUILD_DOCS=OFF \
> -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
> -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
> -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
> -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
> -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
> -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
> -D BUILD_OPENCV_PYTHON3=1 \
> -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \
> -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON \
> -D WITH_XINE=ON \
> -D PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") \
> -D PYTHON3_LIBRARIES=$(python3 -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())") \
> -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON \
> ../

CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:72 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0022 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:77 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0026 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:82 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0042 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.

...

-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WMISSING_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSTRICT_PROTOTYPES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WUNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WINIT_SELF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WPOINTER_ARITH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WSIGN_PROMO - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WSIGN_PROMO - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_NARROWING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_DELETE_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNNAMED_TYPE_TEMPLATE_ARGS - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FDIAGNOSTICS_SHOW_OPTION - Success

...

-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_FVISIBILITY_INLINES_HIDDEN - Failed
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.11", minimum required is "1.2.3")
-- Found TIFF: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (found version "4.1.0")
-- Found JPEG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (found version "80")
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_VARIABLE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_UNUSED_FUNCTION - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_C_WNO_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Found Jasper: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (found version "1.900.1")
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11")
-- Found PNG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (found version "1.6.37")
-- Looking for /usr/include/libpng/png.h
-- Looking for /usr/include/libpng/png.h - found
-- Looking for semaphore.h
-- Looking for semaphore.h - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SHADOW - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNUSED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SIGN_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNDEF - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_MISSING_DECLARATIONS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_UNINITIALIZED - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_SWITCH - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_PARENTHESES - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_ARRAY_BOUNDS - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_EXTRA - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS
-- Performing Test HAVE_CXX_WNO_DEPRECATED_DECLARATIONS - Success
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:275 (message):

...

CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CUDA_nppi_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "opencv_cudev" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudev
    linked by target "opencv_cudev" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudev
    linked by target "opencv_core" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/core
    linked by target "opencv_core" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/core
    linked by target "opencv_cudaarithm" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudaarithm
    linked by target "opencv_cudaarithm" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudaarithm
    linked by target "opencv_flann" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/flann
    linked by target "opencv_flann" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/flann
    linked by target "opencv_hdf" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf
    linked by target "opencv_hdf" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/hdf
    linked by target "opencv_imgproc" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/imgproc
    linked by target "opencv_imgproc" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/imgproc
    linked by target "opencv_ml" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/ml
    linked by target "opencv_ml" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/ml
    linked by target "opencv_reg" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/reg
    linked by target "opencv_reg" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/reg
    linked by target "opencv_surface_matching" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/surface_matching
    linked by target "opencv_surface_matching" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/surface_matching
    linked by target "opencv_video" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/video
    linked by target "opencv_video" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/video
    linked by target "opencv_cudabgsegm" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudabgsegm
    linked by target "opencv_cudabgsegm" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudabgsegm
    linked by target "opencv_cudafilters" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudafilters
    linked by target "opencv_cudafilters" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudafilters
    linked by target "opencv_cudaimgproc" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudaimgproc
    linked by target "opencv_cudaimgproc" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudaimgproc
    linked by target "opencv_cudawarping" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudawarping
    linked by target "opencv_cudawarping" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudawarping
    linked by target "opencv_dnn" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/dnn
    linked by target "opencv_dnn" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/dnn
    linked by target "opencv_fuzzy" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/fuzzy
    linked by target "opencv_fuzzy" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/fuzzy
    linked by target "opencv_imgcodecs" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/imgcodecs
    linked by target "opencv_imgcodecs" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/imgcodecs
    linked by target "opencv_photo" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/photo
    linked by target "opencv_photo" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/photo
    linked by target "opencv_shape" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/shape
    linked by target "opencv_shape" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/shape
    linked by target "opencv_videoio" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/videoio
    linked by target "opencv_videoio" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/videoio
    linked by target "opencv_cudacodec" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudacodec
    linked by target "opencv_cudacodec" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudacodec
    linked by target "opencv_highgui" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/highgui
    linked by target "opencv_highgui" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/highgui
    linked by target "opencv_objdetect" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/objdetect
    linked by target "opencv_objdetect" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/objdetect
    linked by target "opencv_plot" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/plot
    linked by target "opencv_plot" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/plot
    linked by target "opencv_xobjdetect" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/xobjdetect
    linked by target "opencv_xobjdetect" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/xobjdetect
    linked by target "opencv_xphoto" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/xphoto
    linked by target "opencv_xphoto" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/xphoto
    linked by target "opencv_bgsegm" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/bgsegm
    linked by target "opencv_bgsegm" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/bgsegm
    linked by target "opencv_bioinspired" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/bioinspired
    linked by target "opencv_bioinspired" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/bioinspired
    linked by target "opencv_dpm" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/dpm
    linked by target "opencv_dpm" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/dpm
    linked by target "opencv_face" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/face
    linked by target "opencv_face" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/face
    linked by target "opencv_features2d" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/features2d
    linked by target "opencv_features2d" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/features2d
    linked by target "opencv_line_descriptor" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/line_descriptor
    linked by target "opencv_line_descriptor" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/line_descriptor
    linked by target "opencv_saliency" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/saliency
    linked by target "opencv_saliency" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/saliency
    linked by target "opencv_text" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/text
    linked by target "opencv_text" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/text
    linked by target "opencv_calib3d" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/calib3d
    linked by target "opencv_calib3d" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/calib3d
    linked by target "opencv_ccalib" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/ccalib
    linked by target "opencv_ccalib" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/ccalib
    linked by target "opencv_cudafeatures2d" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudafeatures2d
    linked by target "opencv_cudafeatures2d" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudafeatures2d
    linked by target "opencv_cudalegacy" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudalegacy
    linked by target "opencv_cudalegacy" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudalegacy
    linked by target "opencv_cudaobjdetect" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudaobjdetect
    linked by target "opencv_cudaobjdetect" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudaobjdetect
    linked by target "opencv_cudaoptflow" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudaoptflow
    linked by target "opencv_cudaoptflow" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudaoptflow
    linked by target "opencv_cudastereo" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudastereo
    linked by target "opencv_cudastereo" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/cudastereo
    linked by target "opencv_cvv" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/cvv
    linked by target "opencv_cvv" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/cvv
    linked by target "opencv_datasets" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/datasets
    linked by target "opencv_datasets" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/datasets
    linked by target "opencv_rgbd" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/rgbd
    linked by target "opencv_rgbd" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/rgbd
    linked by target "opencv_stereo" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/stereo
    linked by target "opencv_stereo" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/stereo
    linked by target "opencv_structured_light" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/structured_light
    linked by target "opencv_structured_light" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/structured_light
    linked by target "opencv_superres" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/superres
    linked by target "opencv_superres" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/superres
    linked by target "opencv_tracking" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/tracking
    linked by target "opencv_tracking" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/tracking
    linked by target "opencv_videostab" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/videostab
    linked by target "opencv_videostab" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/videostab
    linked by target "opencv_xfeatures2d" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d
    linked by target "opencv_xfeatures2d" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/xfeatures2d
    linked by target "opencv_ximgproc" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/ximgproc
    linked by target "opencv_ximgproc" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/ximgproc
    linked by target "opencv_aruco" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/aruco
    linked by target "opencv_aruco" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/aruco
    linked by target "opencv_optflow" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/optflow
    linked by target "opencv_optflow" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/optflow
    linked by target "opencv_sfm" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/sfm
    linked by target "opencv_sfm" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv_contrib/modules/sfm
    linked by target "opencv_stitching" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/stitching
    linked by target "opencv_stitching" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/modules/stitching
    linked by target "opencv_traincascade" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/apps/traincascade
    linked by target "opencv_createsamples" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/apps/createsamples
    linked by target "opencv_annotation" in directory /home/boxboy/opencv/apps/annotation

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/boxboy/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: Did you try the response suggested here? [CMake Error: Variables are set to NOTFOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46584000/cmake-error-variables-are-set-to-notfound) The error in the other post is **exactly the same** as yours, and the build situation appears to be similar.

Comment: I'm wondering if you really need to build OpenCV 3.1 from source. [Ubuntu 20.04 comes with libopencv 4.2.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libopencv-dev).